# Using OpenX to serve text links that search engines can see?

Tags: javascript, openx

I am currently using OpenX to serve rotating text links. However, the invocation code is javascript so I don't think search engines can spider these links. Is there another solution or a way to modify OpenX to serve links that search engines can index. An example ad is here http://www.glumbo.com/ad.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is what's called a "Local Mode Tag" invocation type in the self-hosted version of OpenX which it looks like you are using. However, this requires the ad server to be on the same physical host as the website. However even if this works (I've not used it, so I can't speak for how it works), or if you use the JS or iframe invocations, then the URL OpenX will generate for the link still won't be direct (it'll redirect via the ad server) otherwise you'll have no way to track the number of clicks on a link.

Finally, it's against Google's rules to sell "search friendly" links on a website, and you could be penalised in search results if Google catches you selling links in that way. So if the aim of this is to sell Google friendly links I would advise against it anyway. Good luck!

Comment: So there's no way to do this on OpenX?